# Remove all children from a XML Node PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

I want to remove all children from a XML Node using PHP DOM, is there any difference between:

A)

```
while ($parentNode->hasChildNodes()){
   $parentNode->removeChild($parentNode->childNodes->item(0));
 }
```

AND

B)

```
$node->nodeValue = "";
```

I prefer the second one, seems like I am getting the same result but I'm not sure.

Thanks,
Carlos

Comment: I prefer the first, since without intricately knowing how the DOM works it's easy to see what's going on (And as such it's more readable IMHO)...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the thing is I love one-line-code :). Anyway, Is there any difference?

Comment: using version B causes some strange characters in my case if the node has more than one child. No difference with a single child though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`removeChild()` is the more "proper" way of doing things. While you can set the contents of that node to `""` and this will acquire the desired effect, calling `removeChild()` is much more apparent as to what is going on.  However, it would be my assumption that, in a minuscule level, `nodeValue()` is slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 28):

Slightly tighter:

```
  while ($parentNode->hasChildNodes()) {
    $parentNode->removeChild($parentNode->firstChild);
  }
```

Comment: True, but it doesn't actually answer the question (which might have been edited since) seemingly posed ;)